# Version update to SELNEIUM 4.7.0 throwing NoSuchMethod Exception for Pagefactory

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, page-factory

I'm changing my selenium porject from 3.141 to 4.7.0 but i'm seeing NoSuchElementException on PageFactory Initialization.

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
public WebElementsLogin(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(this.driver, this);
    }
```

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext, java.lang.Object)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using selenium 4.7.1 and JDK 11:

```
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
public class Google {
    private WebDriver driver;
    @FindBy(name = "q")
    private WebElement searchField;
    
    public Google(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public  void searchFor(String text){
        searchField.sendKeys(text);
        searchField.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    }

    public void navigateTo(){
        driver.get("https://google.com");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver chrome = new ChromeDriver();
        Google google = new Google(chrome);
        google.navigateTo();
        google.searchFor("Selenium");

    }
}
```

Everything works as expected.

Correct this line:

```
PageFactory.initElements(this.driver, this);
```

Comment: It got fixed thanks @Alex karamfilov